# PHP mail() function not delivering mail

Tags: php, linux, sendmail

I have a slight problem. I am using a working script (works on my testing account - shared server) to send a mail through PHP using the mail() function.

I just got a dedicated server, and I haven't been able to get the function to work. I've spent the last 10 or so hours reading various documentations on BIND (for the SPF record), dovecot, sendmail and postfix trying various things to get this to work.

There is clearly something that I am missing.

So we know the PHP code works fine. All the headers are fine everything. We know this as it's a direct copy from my testing account. So the problem must arise somewhere in the server config. The path to sendmail is correct, and sendmail is (apparently) working fine. I've set up the script to now deliver "Sent" or "Error" based on the boolean result from the PHP mail() function. That is:

```
if(mail($blah,$blah,$blah,$blah,$blah)) { echo "Sent"; } else { echo "Error";}
```

And the result ALWAYS comes up as "Sent" - however, the email never arrives. Can someone suggest things to check, as I'm completely new to this (24 hours or so!).

Thanks in advance.

Ryan

Comment: Did you check span folder on the recipient email

Comment: What mail daemon do you have running on your dedicated server?

Comment: John, the tags list sendmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [mailq command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_mailq.htm) to see if there are errors? Here's an [answer to a similar question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/61586/sendmail-queues-mail-doesnt-send#61692) with more detail.

Comment: Hey all - thanks for the replies. Nothing in the spam filter. I am running sendmail, but I also have postfix running. OK, so some progress, when I was typing in mailq before it was returning '0' but now I'm typing in "mailq -Ac" and I'm getting 8 errors.

Comment: Hi again Matt. i worked through and sent an email to my gmail account via the google smtp server. It got through but ended up in the spam folder with no sender etc. So am I right in assuming that this is an SPF problem? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Cleaned out the clientmqueue as per the instructions and now mails won't send at all... oh dear. This is really not becoming fun!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a SMTP server. The php mail function will not work unless you install one. For example, under linux, you can install postfix. Under windows, MS exchange is an example.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, yes, postfix is running. I'm not sure whether that is the problem or not. I'm getting a deferred error in mailq.