# I cannot seem to get my form to successfully email

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

This is my first time creating a website combining AJAX, JavaScript, PHP, and HTML. Basically, I have a modal that pops up when you click "contact me" with a form inside. The reason I've chosen to use AJAX is because I don't want the page to refresh or remove the modal. I just want it to say something simple afterwards inside the modal.

My problem is, I don't receive the email from the form once I hit submit, and when I trace the emails sent to my address from my server, they don't even show up. This isn't my first time building a web form or using PHP/HTML, so I'm convinced the problem has to be with the AJAX.

So, here is what I have, and I can't seem to figure out why it won't work...

PHP:

```
<?php
$email_to="conrad.h.appel.iv@gmail.com";
$email_subject="Form Submission";

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

function clean_string($string)
{
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "E-Mail Address: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message);

$headers='From: '.$email."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();
@mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
die();
?>
```

Javascript/AJAX:

```
function submitForm() {
    var request;
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(message);

    var the_data = "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    /* My attempt to try some jQuery.... Didn't work either
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "formsubmit.php",
        data: { name: $('#name'), email: $('#email'), message: ('#message') }           
            })*/

    request.open("POST","formsubmit.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(the_data);
    $('#contactform').fadeOut();
    $('#contactsuccess').fadeIn();
}
```

Also the submit button, just in case that is an issue...

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitForm()"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Submit!</button>
```

Edit: Also, I'm having trouble with this same code in that it refreshes the page, the exact thing I didn't want it to do. Due to this, I can't see my Javascript console or anything. I assumed AJAX would remove the refresh but it hasn't. How do I fix this as well?

Comment: First thing I'd try would be removing the error suppression from the `mail()` call

Comment: On a side note, to get the jquery to work replace `$('#name')`, `$('#email')` and `$('#message')` with `name`, `email` and `message`.

Comment: done any basic debuggin? checked that the ajax call is properly sending over data? `var_dump($_POST)` in php show anything? did mail() return boolean FALSE to indicate failure, which you've blindly suppressed anyways? checked your mail server's logs for any errors?

Comment: Your `mail` call is vulnerable to mail header injection. Whitelist the input values in the headers.

Comment: Mail() is not guaranteed to be delivered.  Try mailq()

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632173/php-mail-function-not-delivering-mail

Comment: For jquery it is much easier to just use `serialize()` then you don't have to worry about each individual element.

Comment: Do you have firebug installed? You can see the ajax post there and see if you are encountering any errors.

Comment: `$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";` shouldn't be `.=` as `$email_message` hasn't be initialized.

Comment: Is there an `action` on your `<form>`?

Comment: @andrewsi I have done so. I'm now discovering I have no access to my PHP logs on my server... I sent a support ticket to the servermaster to gain access.

Comment: @Pitchinnate There is no action. Do I need one? I assumed the AJAX would handle that.

Comment: No you don't need one just trying to get all info to help debug.

Comment: Try using http://swiftmailer.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using jQuery for fetching inputs values, use `$.ajax()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. Your first approach (now commented) didn't work because you were using the object instead of the value ( `$('#name')` vs `$('#name').val()` ).

The page will reload because there is no return value. Use

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="return submitForm();"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Submit!</button>
```

And also add `return false;` at the end of your function.

To see if there is a problem with your PHP script, I suggest the following:

1. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your file
2. Remove `@` of your mail function
3. In your JS function:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       [...]
       success: function(msg) {
           alert(msg);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: You should also put the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` code inside the success event. There you could check if email was sent (empty `msg`) or if there was some error (not empty `msg`).